# How to resolve a JavaScript XSS vulnerability issue

Tags: javascript, coverity

I have a JavaScript AJAX call that pulls in HTML code into an MVC form.

Coverity flags that because it wants me to sanitize JavaScript tags. Quite rightly because you don't want some hacker to go in and mess things right up.

I put in a Trusted HTML Policy. That satisfies Coverity. But now the HTML code shows up as plain-text on the screen.

So `$(target).html(result)` is no longer behaving how I expected it to.

I tried different methods: `innerHTML`, `$.parseHTML()` and `.text().html()` all do not give me the desired results.

I even commented out the TrustedHTML policy and put in a replace function instead. That didn't work.

All I have is a string of HTML showing up as plain text on the screen.

I comment out the TrustedHTML and the replace function and it works as intended. But Coverity hates it.

Comment: It's unclear what you mean by "*you don't want some hacker to go in and mess things right up.*" It all depends on where you are pulling the html string from and whether that is trusted. Evaluate whether you actually are vulnerable to XSS or not, a Coverity warning cannot do that - it can only give you a hint where to look.

Comment: Try [purify-html](https://www.npmjs.com/package/purify-html)

Answer (score -3):

After a few days of doing some workshopping with this problem, I have used the following and it seems to satisfy Coverity.

**Treat this as a bare bones solution.** Coverity wants a Trusted HTML policy. The programmer will need to beef it up to remediate any and all security issues that arise.

```
const escapeHTMLPolicy =
    trustedTypes.createPolicy("newEscapePolicy", {
        createHTML: (string) => {
            const policyWhitelist = [];
            // be sure to escape your whitelisted data
            policyWhitelist.push("<script type=\"text/javascript\">");

            // . . . other functioning to clear up
            // other vulnerabilities . . .

            // This will now return trusted HTML data along with anything you wish to whitelist.
            if (string.includes("<script") && !policyWhitelist.some(item => string === item)) {
                string.replace(/<script.*/g, "")
            }
            return string;
        }
    });
```

Use this function like so:

```
    $.ajax({
        // something . . .
        success: function (response) {
                        var htmlContent = escapeHTMLPolicy.createHTML(response);
                        var htmlNode = htmlContent.toString();
                        $(targetDiv).html(htmlNode);
                }
    });
```

Comment: There are lots of ways to inject JavaScript outside of `<script` tags.

Comment: I agree. Putting something inside of a TrustedHTML object seems to be acceptable to Coverity.

Comment: Ok, but you might as well just suppress the Coverity warning then, because you're "solving" the problem without solving the actual underlying **security problem**. If you're not interested in closing the actual vulnerability but instead just want to suppress the warning by whatever means, then you're not actually getting value out of Coverity, and you shouldn't use it. If anything, you've done real harm because you are implying to future readers of your code that you've made the value returned from the server safe from XSS, when it certainly is not.

Comment: Then the best way to treat this answer as a skeleton. As you pointed out, there are other ways of putting in DOM XSS into the code. The Trusted HTML Policy can absolutely be fleshed out.